# minimum of last 6 values in a list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this question from codechef:
https://www.codechef.com/OCT19B/problems/S10E

> Chef wants to buy a new phone, but he is not willing to spend a lot of
>   money. Instead, he checks the price of his chosen model everyday and
>   waits for the price to drop to an acceptable value. So far, he has
>   observed the price for N days (numbere 1 through N); for each valid i,
>   the price on the i-th day was Pi dollars.
>
> On each day, Chef considers the price of the phone to be good if it is strictly smaller than all the prices he has observed during the
>   previous five days. If there is no record of the price on some of the
>   previous five days (because Chef has not started checking the price on
>   that day yet), then Chef simply ignores that previous day ― we could
>   say that he considers the price on that day to be infinite.
>
> Now, Chef is wondering ― on how many days has he considered the price to be good? Find the number of these days.

This is what I have done and in all the test cases this gives correct result (as per me).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# Number of test cases
T = int(input())

# for each test case do the following
for i in range(T):
    N = int(input()) # number of days
    P = list(map(int, input().split())) # list containing all the prices
    G = 1 #number of good days. Day 1 is always a good day hence start with 1


    # since price on a given day should be STRICTLY lesser than any of the
    # previous 5 days, price on the day must be minimum of the 6 values
    # (5 previous and today). Also the day's price must not be equal to any of
    # the other  values (STRICTLY)
    for i in range(5,N):
        if(min(P[i-5: i+1]) == P[i]) and (P[i] not in P[i-5: i]):
            G = G + 1

    print(G)
```

But it is still not accepted as answer, what am I doing wrong?
Also any comments on a better approach to solve this is very much welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to start your loop with `1`: `for i in range(1,N):` not `for i in range(5,N):` because days from i = 1 to i = 4 can be good.
2. To avoid problems with negative indices use `max` function with zero as second argument.

All changes applied lead to this:

```
for i in range(1,N):
    if(min(P[max(i-5, 0): i+1]) == P[i]) and (P[i] not in P[max(i-5, 0): i]):
        G = G + 1
```

Comment: Oh yeah I missed point 1 while forming the solution. Also thanks for the trick to work there with negative indices. Did not know we could use `max` like that

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if this answers your question in the 'best' way as I am fairly new to Python but here's my crack at *your* question.

We take a list with > 6 entries. List = [101, 102, 95, 124, 612, 95, 123, 612]
Now we want to grab the last six entries in that list and find the minimum.

```
def minList(P):
    list2 = []
    for i in range(6):
        list2.append(P[-i])
    return min(list2)
```

This outputs 95.

In theory, although bulky, you could send your values into the function above to get the minimum of the previous 6 days.

Comment: `List[-6:]` creates a new list with the last 6 elements of `List`, and `min(List[-6:])` would find the minimum.